# How to determine module path in drush which is outside of Drupal root?

Tags: drush

I've downloaded Coder (7.x-2.x) module in the following way:

```
drush -y dl coder-7.x-2.x --destination=~/.drush && drush cc drush
```

And I would like to call function (`coder_review_reviews()`) from `drush` (using `eval`) which is defined in `~/.drush/coder/coder_review/coder_review.common.inc` and I need to include that file first, but I don't know how to determine my module path.

Normally when module is within Drupal root, you can use [`module_load_include()`](https://api.drupal.org/module_load_include) for that, but this function is not available when you're calling `drush` outside of your core. It seems I can't use [`dd`](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/1733) either.

How can I achieve that without hardcoding the path to the module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Drush, the right way to do this is to use `drush_invoke_process()` to call a Drush function in coder that calls `coder_review_reviews()` for you, and returns the result as the function result of the Drush command implementation.  I did not check to see if coder does this.

If the service you need is not exported, the alternative is to call `drush_get_commandfiles()`.  The result you will get is a key / value pair, where the key 'coder' has the value of the full path to the coder.drush.inc file.

When commands do not export the functionality you need, it is better to submit a patch on their project providing the access you need. Directly including .inc files and calling internal functions is fragile, and at risk of breaking in new versions of the project.

Answer (score 0):

So far I have found the following workaround by using [ReflectionClass](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php), for example:

```
drush ev 'require_once dirname((new ReflectionFunction("drush_coder_review"))->getFileName()) . "/coder_review.common.inc"; print_r(array_keys(coder_review_reviews()));'
```